# Dart. Convert String to List<int>

Tags: flutter, dart

Question in dart:

How can I convert a `String` like this:

"[137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10]"

to type `List<Int>`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
json.decode()
```

Meaning....

```
String value = "[137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10]"

List<int> list = json.decode(value).cast<int>();
```

Answer (score 4):

Follow the below steps.

1. Remove the '[]'
2. Use `split()` method
3. Turn it to an int List

   ```
    List<int> list = value.replaceAll('[', '')
                     .replaceAll(']', '').split(',')
                     .map<int>((e) { 
                     return int.parse(e);
                     }).toList();

    print(list);// [137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` like this:

```
 String str = "[137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10]";
  
  List<int> intList = str.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[\[\], ]'), '').split('').map(int.parse).toList();
  
  print(intList);
```

happy coding...